# How do you turn a string from an HTML file to a number?

Tags: javascript, string, integer

I want to turn a string in an HTML document to a number, but if I try to use Number() or parseInt() with a document.getElementByID it turns to NaN (well I would think that too but I didn't know any other option). Here is a code example:

```
function together() {
let base = document.getElementById("Base");
let add = document.getElementById("Addition");
let sumshow = document.getElementById("Sum");
let sum = Number /*or parseInt*/(base) + Number /*or parseInt*/(add);
sumshow.innerHTML = sum;
}
```

github repo if you want full  thing: github.com/SupaSibs/Calculator-Supa

Answer (score 1):

This is becouse you are getting the element instead of the content of the element, you need to get the value or the innerHTML, like this:

```
 //Input case
     let base = document.getElementById("Base").value;
 //Element case
     let add = document.getElementById("Addition").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work rn